# Filter condition using attributes defined in base class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-filters

I have 3 classes `Base`, `Child` and `Other` defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Filter(name = "myFilter", condition = "propBase = 'special'")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Base {
   private String propBase;

   //Getters, Setters
}

@Entity
public class Child extends Base {
   private String propChild;

   //Getters, Setters
}

@Entity
public class Other {
   @Filter(name = "myFilter", condition = "propBase = 'special'")
   private Set<Child> myList;

   //Getters, Setters
}
```

Assume the filter is defined at the package level so it is visible by all the classes that use it.

Using a session with **myFilter** enabled, I retrieve some instance of `Other` from my database. Then, when I try to access the `myList` collection, since the collection is declared as lazy, Hibernate tries to fetch the collection from the database. But, there is something that I didn't expect in the generated SQL query: the alias of table `Child` is used to prefix the `propBase` column, and since this column is not defined in the table `Child` (it is defined in `Base`), I get the following error:

> ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter  - Unknown column 'childAlias.propBase' in
>   'where clause'

According to this [thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=944267), it seems to be the expected behavior but I don't understand how it can be. Also, assuming this is the expected behavior, how to use filtering when the condition uses properties defined in base class?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't have to use the annotation @FilterDef to define the filter? http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/

Comment: @ambiorix As I said in my question, the filter is defined at the package level etc., so yes it is defined using the FilterDef annotation.

Comment: See https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4332

Comment: @ambiorix How is it related to my issue? Thanks

Comment: Fix Version/s:  3.5.0-Beta-2  Maybe you use an older version of Hibernate that doesn't support filters @MappedSuperClass

Comment: @ambiorix I'm using Hibernate 3.6.10.Final. But I don't see how the link you provided is related to my issue. Here, I have an issue when I use filters on an association pointing to a subclass and when the condition uses properties defined in the base class. Also, I don't use here the MappedSuperClass annotation.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem. Maybe you should use the @MappedSuperClass and define the filter there.  Or did you try that already?  greets

Comment: @ambiorix I've tried to apply the filter at the MappedSuperClass level, and it does not solve the issue. I understand why since I need the filter to be applied at the association level not at the class level (the filter was already applied at the class level before).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sql fragment alias -
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter-sql-fragment-alias

```
@Entity
public class Other {
   @Filter(
        name = "filterPropBase", 
        condition = "{b}.propBase='special'",
        aliases={@SqlFragmentAlias(alias="b", entity=Base.class)
   )
   private Set<Child> myList;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Hibernate 4.1 and had the same problem. [This explains](https://github.com/rworsnop/hibernate-orm/blob/HHH-2394/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/annotations/filter/subclass/joined/Club.java) how to tell Hibernate which entity class your condition is actually defined on. Adding aliases to the @Filter annotation fixed the problem for me.

In JPQL select statements, resolving attributes names through inheritance worked directly, BTW.