# Hibernate filter condition: access nested property / use alias

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I hava a `BaseEntity` that defines an `@Id String id`. I want to use a hibernate filter on a `@ManyToOne` relation matching that `id`. I have one more layer of hierarchy, I don't know if it makes a difference, so I'll include it just in case.

```
@Entity
public class Market extends BaseEntity {}

@MappedSuperclass
@FilterDef(name = "market", parameters = @ParamDef(name = "marketId", type = "string"))
@Filter(name = "market", condition = "{alias}.market.id = :marketId")
public abstract class MarketSpecificEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  private Market market;
}

@Entity
public class Product extends MarketSpecificEntity {}
```

As far as I understand, `{alias}` should be replaced with the alias used by hibernate. SQL from `ProductRepository.findAll()`:

```
select product0_.id as id1_1_, product0_.market_id as market_i2_1_ from product product0_ where {alias}.market.id = ?
```

Ommitting the alias works on a non-nested property but on the nested `id` it doesn't (as expected):

```
select product0_.id as id1_1_, product0_.market_id as market_i2_1_ from product product0_ where market.id = ?
```

I also tried using the `aliases` parameter of `@Filter` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14998347/5519485) but I don't understand how to adapt that.

One more note: The comparison must not lead to a `JOIN`. This works because `market.id` is a foreign key saved in the `Product` table, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems like the syntax for `condition` is not JPQL but actual SQL (why?!). This does work: `condition = "market_id = :marketId"`.

Also, there is a way to inject the alias using `$FILTER_PLACEHOLDER$` as seen [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1012172).

Answer (score 0):

Try protected instead of private

```
public abstract class MarketSpecificEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  protected Market market;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't replace `{alias}`.